# Ids must exist in the Container or as a generated column, missing id: id

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin

Any idea of why I'm getting this error, I've tried all naming convention (lowercase / uppercase)

I am using Vaadin, here is a snippet of my code:

```
    public class Usercontainer extends BeanItemContainer<Users> implements Serializable{
    public static final Object[] NATURAL_COL_ORDER = new Object[] {"id", "empCode"};

    public static final String[] COL_HEADERS_ENGLISH = new String[] {"User Id", "Emp code"};

    public Usercontainer() throws IllegalArgumentException {
        super(Users.class);
    }

    public static Usercontainer createTestData(){
        Usercontainer users = null;     
        try
        {
            users = new Usercontainer();
            for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
                Users user = new Users();
                user.setId(i*10);
                user.setEmpcode("C00"+i);
                users.addItem(user);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());}       
        return users;       
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="_user")
public class Users {
    //private String name;
    public int id;
    public String empcode;

        @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getEmpcode() {
        return empcode;
    }
    public void setEmpcode(String empcode) {
        this.empcode = empcode;
    }


}
```

---

```
    public class UserTable extends Table {


    public UserTable(App1Application app){
        setSizeFull();
        setContainerDataSource(app.getDataSource());
        setVisibleColumns(Usercontainer.NATURAL_COL_ORDER);
        setColumnHeaders(Usercontainer.COL_HEADERS_ENGLISH);
        this.setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);
        setSelectable(true);
        setImmediate(true);
        addListener((Property.ValueChangeListener)app);
        setNullSelectionAllowed(false);


    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work.
I'd turn on exception breakpoint and see what it's comparing against.
Look @ your Usercontainer class and make sure it has the right properties in container.model

Comment: Is app.getDataSource() returning the correct object in UserTable's constructor?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `"empCode"` in the `NATURAL_COL_ORDER` then you should use the `getEmpCode()` getter method in the entity class (instead of `getEmpcode()` ) imho.